# RobotFramework_SeleniumLibrary_Browser is launched but mentioned URL is not navigated to

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I'm a beginner in Robotframework Web Automation using with SeleniumLibrary. I was trying to write a simple robot testcase to just launch Chrome browser and navigate to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).
I'm using Pycharm IDE. Python version is 3.7.5, Robot Framework is 3.1.2, Selenium 3.141.0. Also the required packages like RobotFramework, Selenium, RobotFramework-SeleniumLibrary packages are added to Pycharm, Intellibot plugin also added to the Pycharm.
The chrome browser version is 112.0.5615.121, the best matching ChromeDriver downloaded is 112.0.5615.49 and this .exe was kept in Scripts folder under Python37 folder and the same path is provided in Env variables Path.
Now below is my code.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***

Testcase name: Launch and Navigate:
        open browser    www.google.com      chrome
```

When i run this test, chrome browser is launched, but in the URL, it shows this - "data:," and stays there undefenitely. If i close the browser at this stage, get below error details in Pycharm terminal:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Can someone please let me know if this is due to a confugure/setup issue or issue with code with resolution ? I do this in my client remote desktop.

**Output**
[image: Output]

I have also tried below code for the same purpose:

```
*** Settings ***

Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***

${url}      https://www.google.com
${driver_path}      C:/Program Files/Python37/Scripts/chromedriver


*** Test Cases ***
TC_01Launch

        ${chrome_options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver

        Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --no-sandbox
        Create Webdriver  Chrome    executable_path=${driver_path}      
        Open Browser    ${url}    chrome        options=${chrome_options}
```

Answer (score -1):

We need to specify the protocol (http:// or https://) also with the URL. In your case, try:

```
open browser  https://www.google.com  chrome
```

Comment: Hello Pramesh, thanks for the input. This way I tried and same error still.

Comment: can someone please help as above answer was already tried and got the same error.